# Displaying tooltip over a disabled control

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I'm trying to display a tooltip when mouse hovers over a disabled control. Since a disabled control does not handle any events, I have to do that in the parent form. I chose to do this by handling the `MouseMove` event in the parent form. Here's the code that does the job:

```
    void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        m_toolTips.SetToolTip(this, "testing tooltip on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        string tipText = this.m_toolTips.GetToolTip(this);
        if ((tipText != null) && (tipText.Length > 0))
        {
            Point clientLoc = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            Control child = this.GetChildAtPoint(clientLoc);
            if (child != null && child.Enabled == false)
            {
                m_toolTips.ToolTipTitle = "MouseHover On Disabled Control";
                m_toolTips.Show(tipText, this, 10000);
            }
            else
            {
                m_toolTips.ToolTipTitle = "MouseHover Triggerd";
                m_toolTips.Show(tipText, this, 3000);
            }
        }
    }
```

The code does handles the tooltip display for the disabled control. The problem is that when mouse hovers over a disabled control, the tooltip keeps closing and redisplay again. From the display time I added in the tooltip, when mouse is above the parent form, the `MouseMove` event gets called roughly every 3 seconds, so the tooltip gets updated every 3 seconds. But when mouse is over a disabled control, the tooltip refreshes every 1 second. Also, when tooltip refreshes above form, only the text gets updated with a brief flash. But when tooltip refreshes above a disabled control, the tooltip windows closes as if mouse is moving into a enabled control and the tooltip is supposed to be closed. but then the tooltip reappears right away.

Can someone tell me why is this? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer turned out to be a bit simpler, but needed to be applied at all times.

```
void OrderSummaryDetails_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      Control control = GetChildAtPoint(e.Location);
      if (control != null)
      {
          string toolTipString = mFormTips.GetToolTip(control);
          this.mFormTips.ShowAlways = true;
          // trigger the tooltip with no delay and some basic positioning just to give you an idea
          mFormTips.Show(toolTipString, control, control.Width / 2, control.Height / 2);
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi all
Good solution. Please allow me to improve the code, because the tooltip stays on the screen even while the mouse is elsewhere.

            ...
            if (CurrentControl != null)
            {
                ...
                toolTips.Show(...);
                OldControl = CurrentControl; // remember this control
            }
            else if (OldControl != null) // hide the shown tooltip
            {
                toolTips.Hide(OldControl);
                OldControl = null;
            }

Answer (score 19):

you can show the tooltip only once when mouse hits the disbled control and then hide it when mouse leaves it. Pls, take a look at the code below, it should be showing a tooltip message for all the disabled controls on the form

```
private ToolTip     _toolTip = new ToolTip();
private Control     _currentToolTipControl = null; 

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _toolTip.SetToolTip(this.button1, "My button1");
    _toolTip.SetToolTip(this.button2, "My button2");
    _toolTip.SetToolTip(this.textBox1, "My text box");
}

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Control control = GetChildAtPoint(e.Location);
    if (control != null)
    {
        if (!control.Enabled && _currentToolTipControl == null)
        {
            string toolTipString = _toolTip.GetToolTip(control);
            // trigger the tooltip with no delay and some basic positioning just to give you an idea
            _toolTip.Show(toolTipString, control, control.Width/2, control.Height/2);
            _currentToolTipControl = control;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (_currentToolTipControl != null) _toolTip.Hide(_currentToolTipControl);
        _currentToolTipControl = null;
    }
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: This seems to almost work. Some controls are behaving properly while others are still flashing.

Comment: Works better than DJ answer for me. I added an control.Visible check so I didn't pop up tool tips on invisible controls. I also moved the hide block to before the show block and checked if(_currentToolTipControl != null && _currentToolTipControl != control) { ...Hide(); _currentToolTipControl = null; } (without this, a quick move to another disabled control fails to update the tooltip).

Answer (score 5):

In case of TextBox control, making it as readonly solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I tried many but ended up using this simple trick which I think it is more effective.

Create a subclass(CustomControl with just base control in it) which extends UserControl

then instead of setting "Enabled" property to false create a Method which disables just basecontrol in it instead of whole CustomControl.

Set the tool tip on CustomControl still will be able to fire eventhandlers setting the basecontrol disabled. This works wherever CustomControl is in use rather than coding on every form you use with.

Here is the hint.. :)

```
public partial class MyTextBox : UserControl
{
   ...
   ...
   ...


   public void DisableMyTextBox()
    {
        this.txt.Enabled = false;  //txt is the name of Winform-Textbox from my designer
        this.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void EnableMyTextBox()
    {
        this.txt.Enabled = true;
        this.Enabled = true;
    }

    //set the tooltip from properties tab in designer or wherever
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since no one ever pointed this out, this works for any control that exposes `ToolTipService`:

`ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"`

As in this example:

```
<Button Content="OK"
        ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" />
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but this appears to be WPF rather than Winforms as specified by OP.

Comment: @Dave You are correct...now.  I only view questions tagged w/C# and WPF, so I have to assume that at the time I answered it, it was tagged incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
Inspired by the suggestions above in this post, i wrapped it up as an extended ToolTip control specially works for disabled control. 

                // Reference example
                var td = new ToolTipOnDisabledControl();
                this.checkEdit3.Enabled = false;
                td.SetTooltip(this.checkEdit3, "tooltip for disabled 3333333333333");
*/    

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp1
{
    public class ToolTipOnDisabledControl
    {
        #region Fields and Properties

        private Control enabledParentControl;

        private bool isShown;

        public Control TargetControl { get; private set; }

        public string TooltipText { get; private set; }
        public ToolTip ToolTip { get; }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        public ToolTipOnDisabledControl()
        {
            this.ToolTip = new ToolTip();
        }

        public void SetToolTip(Control targetControl, string tooltipText = null)
        {
            this.TargetControl = targetControl;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tooltipText))
            {
                this.TooltipText = this.ToolTip.GetToolTip(targetControl);
            }
            else
            {
                this.TooltipText = tooltipText;
            }

            if (targetControl.Enabled)
            {
                this.enabledParentControl = null;
                this.isShown = false;
                this.ToolTip.SetToolTip(this.TargetControl, this.TooltipText);
                return;
            }

            this.enabledParentControl = targetControl.Parent;
            while (!this.enabledParentControl.Enabled && this.enabledParentControl.Parent != null)
            {
                this.enabledParentControl = this.enabledParentControl.Parent;
            }

            if (!this.enabledParentControl.Enabled)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to set tool tip because failed to find an enabled parent control.");
            }

            this.enabledParentControl.MouseMove += this.EnabledParentControl_MouseMove;
            this.TargetControl.EnabledChanged += this.TargetControl_EnabledChanged;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            if (this.TargetControl != null)
            {
                this.ToolTip.Hide(this.TargetControl);
                this.TargetControl.EnabledChanged -= this.TargetControl_EnabledChanged;
                this.TargetControl = null;
            }

            if (this.enabledParentControl != null)
            {
                this.enabledParentControl.MouseMove -= this.EnabledParentControl_MouseMove;
                this.enabledParentControl = null;
            }

            this.isShown = false;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private void EnabledParentControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Location.X >= this.TargetControl.Left &&
                e.Location.X <= this.TargetControl.Right &&
                e.Location.Y >= this.TargetControl.Top &&
                e.Location.Y <= this.TargetControl.Bottom)
            {
                if (!this.isShown)
                {
                    this.ToolTip.Show(this.TooltipText, this.TargetControl, this.TargetControl.Width / 2, this.TargetControl.Height / 2, this.ToolTip.AutoPopDelay);
                    this.isShown = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.ToolTip.Hide(this.TargetControl);
                this.isShown = false;
            }
        }

        private void TargetControl_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TargetControl.Enabled)
            {
                TargetControl.EnabledChanged -= TargetControl_EnabledChanged;
                enabledParentControl.MouseMove -= EnabledParentControl_MouseMove;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: While code only answers are allowed, they are discouraged. Consider adding some explanation along side the code.

Comment: Better solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: EnabledParentControl_MouseMove... else -> else if(this.isShown)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this problem

I have an application that generates code automatically for a PIC32MX.

The application has 3 Tab Pages text = PWM, ADC and UART.

On each Tab Page I have one Check Box text = RPA0

The intention is, when a peripheral uses RPA0, the other peripheral is prevented 
from using that pin, by disabling it on the other pages, and a tooltip text must pop up 
on the disabled check boxs saying (example "Used by PWM") 
what peripheral is using that pin.

The problem is that the tooltip text won't pop up on a disabled check box.

To solve the problem, I just removed the text of the check boxes and inserted labels with the text the check box should have.

When a check box is checked, the other check boxes are disabled and the label next to it takes a tool tip text.

As the label is enabled, the tooltip text pops up, even on a disabled check box.

Double the work, half the complexity.

Here is the code and the designer for C# 2010

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void cb_ADC_RPA0_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /* Disable pin on other peripherals */
            cb_UART_RPA0.Enabled = !((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
            cb_PWM_RPA0.Enabled = !((CheckBox)sender).Checked;

            SetTootTip((CheckBox)sender, lbl_PWM_RPA0, lbl_UART_RPA0, "ADC");

        }



        private void cb_PWM_RPA0_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /* Disable pin on other peripherals */
            cb_UART_RPA0.Enabled = !((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
            cb_ADC_RPA0.Enabled = !((CheckBox)sender).Checked;

            SetTootTip((CheckBox)sender, lbl_ADC_RPA0, lbl_UART_RPA0, "PWM");
        }

        private void cb_UART_RPA0_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /* Disable pin on other peripherals */
            cb_ADC_RPA0.Enabled = !((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
            cb_PWM_RPA0.Enabled = !((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
            SetTootTip((CheckBox)sender, lbl_ADC_RPA0, lbl_PWM_RPA0, "UART");

        }

        void SetTootTip(CheckBox sender, Label lbl1, Label lbl2, string text)
        {
            /* Update tooltip on the other labels */
            if (sender.Checked)
            {
                toolTip1.SetToolTip(lbl1, "Used by " + text);
                toolTip1.SetToolTip(lbl2, "Used by " + text);
            }
            else
            {
                toolTip1.SetToolTip(lbl1, "");
                toolTip1.SetToolTip(lbl2, "");
            }
        }
    }
}


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
            this.tpPWM = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.tpUART = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.tpADC = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.cb_PWM_RPA0 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            this.cb_ADC_RPA0 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            this.lbl_PWM_RPA0 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.lbl_ADC_RPA0 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.toolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);
            this.lbl_UART_RPA0 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.cb_UART_RPA0 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
            this.tpPWM.SuspendLayout();
            this.tpUART.SuspendLayout();
            this.tpADC.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tabControl1
            // 
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tpPWM);
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tpUART);
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tpADC);
            this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
            this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(629, 296);
            this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // tpPWM
            // 
            this.tpPWM.Controls.Add(this.lbl_PWM_RPA0);
            this.tpPWM.Controls.Add(this.cb_PWM_RPA0);
            this.tpPWM.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
            this.tpPWM.Name = "tpPWM";
            this.tpPWM.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.tpPWM.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(621, 270);
            this.tpPWM.TabIndex = 0;
            this.tpPWM.Text = "PWM";
            this.tpPWM.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // tpUART
            // 
            this.tpUART.Controls.Add(this.cb_UART_RPA0);
            this.tpUART.Controls.Add(this.lbl_UART_RPA0);
            this.tpUART.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
            this.tpUART.Name = "tpUART";
            this.tpUART.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.tpUART.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(621, 270);
            this.tpUART.TabIndex = 1;
            this.tpUART.Text = "UART";
            this.tpUART.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // tpADC
            // 
            this.tpADC.Controls.Add(this.lbl_ADC_RPA0);
            this.tpADC.Controls.Add(this.cb_ADC_RPA0);
            this.tpADC.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
            this.tpADC.Name = "tpADC";
            this.tpADC.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.tpADC.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(621, 270);
            this.tpADC.TabIndex = 2;
            this.tpADC.Text = "ADC";
            this.tpADC.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // cb_PWM_RPA0
            // 
            this.cb_PWM_RPA0.AutoSize = true;
            this.cb_PWM_RPA0.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 65);
            this.cb_PWM_RPA0.Name = "cb_PWM_RPA0";
            this.cb_PWM_RPA0.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(15, 14);
            this.cb_PWM_RPA0.TabIndex = 0;
            this.cb_PWM_RPA0.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.cb_PWM_RPA0.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cb_PWM_RPA0_CheckedChanged);
            // 
            // cb_ADC_RPA0
            // 
            this.cb_ADC_RPA0.AutoSize = true;
            this.cb_ADC_RPA0.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 65);
            this.cb_ADC_RPA0.Name = "cb_ADC_RPA0";
            this.cb_ADC_RPA0.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(15, 14);
            this.cb_ADC_RPA0.TabIndex = 1;
            this.cb_ADC_RPA0.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.cb_ADC_RPA0.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cb_ADC_RPA0_CheckedChanged);
            // 
            // lbl_PWM_RPA0
            // 
            this.lbl_PWM_RPA0.AutoSize = true;
            this.lbl_PWM_RPA0.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(38, 65);
            this.lbl_PWM_RPA0.Name = "lbl_PWM_RPA0";
            this.lbl_PWM_RPA0.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
            this.lbl_PWM_RPA0.TabIndex = 1;
            this.lbl_PWM_RPA0.Text = "RPA0";
            // 
            // lbl_ADC_RPA0
            // 
            this.lbl_ADC_RPA0.AutoSize = true;
            this.lbl_ADC_RPA0.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(38, 66);
            this.lbl_ADC_RPA0.Name = "lbl_ADC_RPA0";
            this.lbl_ADC_RPA0.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
            this.lbl_ADC_RPA0.TabIndex = 2;
            this.lbl_ADC_RPA0.Text = "RPA0";
            // 
            // lbl_UART_RPA0
            // 
            this.lbl_UART_RPA0.AutoSize = true;
            this.lbl_UART_RPA0.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(37, 65);
            this.lbl_UART_RPA0.Name = "lbl_UART_RPA0";
            this.lbl_UART_RPA0.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
            this.lbl_UART_RPA0.TabIndex = 4;
            this.lbl_UART_RPA0.Text = "RPA0";
            // 
            // cb_UART_RPA0
            // 
            this.cb_UART_RPA0.AutoSize = true;
            this.cb_UART_RPA0.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 65);
            this.cb_UART_RPA0.Name = "cb_UART_RPA0";
            this.cb_UART_RPA0.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(15, 14);
            this.cb_UART_RPA0.TabIndex = 5;
            this.cb_UART_RPA0.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.cb_UART_RPA0.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cb_UART_RPA0_CheckedChanged);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(758, 429);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tpPWM.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tpPWM.PerformLayout();
            this.tpUART.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tpUART.PerformLayout();
            this.tpADC.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tpADC.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tpPWM;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lbl_PWM_RPA0;
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox cb_PWM_RPA0;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tpUART;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tpADC;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lbl_ADC_RPA0;
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox cb_ADC_RPA0;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip toolTip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox cb_UART_RPA0;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lbl_UART_RPA0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new UserControl which only contains a button.

```
public partial class TooltipButton : UserControl
{
    public TooltipButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public new bool Enabled
    {
        get { return button.Enabled; }
        set { button.Enabled = value; }
    }

    [Category("Appearance")]
    [Description("The text displayed by the button.")]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [Bindable(true)]
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return button.Text; }
        set { button.Text = value; }
    }

    [Category("Action")]
    [Description("Occurs when the button is clicked.")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public new event EventHandler Click;

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Bubble event up to parent
        Click?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Serge_Yubenko's code worked on disabled buttons , but in order to stop the flashing make sure the tooltip pops up away from the button - just don't position it half way down the control but do this:

mFormTips.Show(toolTipString, control, control.Width / 2, control.Height);

instead of
mFormTips.Show(toolTipString, control, control.Width / 2, control.Height / 2);

This seems to follow the usual tooltip placement too...

Answer (score 0):

So, I came across this post in my efforts to do the same thing, being the top result on Google. I had already considered the mouse move event and while the answers here did help, they didn't provide me with exactly what I wanted - that being a perfect recreation of the original show tooltip event.

The problem I discovered was this: For whatever reason in the API, ToolTip.Show turns the Mouse Move Event into effectively a Mouse Hover Event. Which is why the tooltip keeps flashing.

The workaround as suggested was to keep the tooltip on always show, or to display the tooltip away from the control, but that wouldn't be a faithful recreation, from the show to the timed fade. The answer would suggest that a block to prevent further execution of the code is needed - the reality was 2 blocks in the event code (One of which has no earthly reason existing and yet without it a timed event fires twice ***), a double delclaration of the control location, one inside the event, one class wide, and another class wide to check if the mouse is over a control, a class wide timer, and a Mouse Leave event to clean up due to too fast mouse movement away from the panel housing the control.

As you will see there are two events on the timer, both functions for them are in the event code as they need to reference variables get/set in the code. They can be moved out, but would then need class wide declarations on the variables, and they cause no harm where they are. FYI: "ToolTips" in the code is referencing the ToolTip control I have on the form.

*** Just to expand. If you look at the code you'll see that IsTipReset could be replaced with IsShown - after all they end up at the same value as each other. The reason for IsTipRest is this: If IsShown is used then while moving the mouse inside the control while the tootip is showing will cause a slight hiccup when the tooltip fades and very very very briefly another tooltip will popup. Using IsTipReset stops that. I have no idea why and maybe someone will spot it because I sure can't! Lol.

This is my first post here, and I realise it is an old thread, but I just wanted to share the fruits of my labour. As I said, my goal was a faithful recreation of tooltip and I think I achieved it. Enjoy!

```
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;
private readonly Timer MouseTimer = new();
private Control? Ctrl;
private bool IsControl = false;

private void TopMenuMouseMove (object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    Panel Pnl = (Panel)sender;
    Control Area = Pnl.GetChildAtPoint (e.Location);
    bool IsShown = false;
    bool IsTipReset = false;
    if (Area != null && Area.Enabled == false && Area.Visible == true) {
        Ctrl = Pnl.GetChildAtPoint (e.Location);
        Point Position = e.Location;

        if (IsControl) { IsShown = true; } else if (!IsControl) { IsControl = true; IsShown = false; }

        if (!IsShown) {
            MouseTimer.Interval = ToolTips.InitialDelay;
            MouseTimer.Tick += new EventHandler (TimerToolTipShow!);
            MouseTimer.Start ();
        }

        void TimerToolTipShow (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (!IsTipReset) {
                MouseTimer.Dispose ();
                string Txt = ToolTips.GetToolTip (Ctrl) + " (Disabled)";
                Position.Offset (-Ctrl.Left, 16);
                ToolTips.Show (Txt, Ctrl, Position);
                MouseTimer.Interval = ToolTips.AutoPopDelay;
                MouseTimer.Tick += new EventHandler (TimerToolTipReset!);
                MouseTimer.Start ();
                IsShown = true;
                IsTipReset = true;
            }
        }

        void TimerToolTipReset (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (IsShown) {
                MouseTimer.Dispose ();
                IsShown = false;
                ToolTips.Hide (Ctrl);
            }
        }

    }
    else if (Area == null) {
        if (Ctrl != null) {
            MouseTimer.Dispose ();
            IsShown = false;
            IsControl = false;
            ToolTips.Hide (Ctrl);
            Ctrl = null;
        }
    }
}

private void TopMenuMouseLeave (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Ctrl != null) {
        MouseTimer.Dispose ();
        IsControl = false;
        ToolTips.Hide (Ctrl);
        Ctrl = null;
    }
}
```