# C# Tooltip on TabPage

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, tooltip, tabpage

How can I show `Tooltip` text on my own `TabPages` extends from `TabPages` just added some extra variables and using `DrawItem` event.

I've generate them in method.

```
ISIMtabPage newTab = new ISIMtabPage();

// setting up newTab
string contactName = getContactName(object);

chatFormTabs.TabPages.Add(newTab);

toolTip1.SetToolTip((ISIMtabPage)chatFormTabs.TabPages[chatId], contactName);
```

But if I hover on the tab it doesn't do anything.

I've `TabControl.ShowToolTips` enabled.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would check `toolTip1.SetToolTip`

example for Tooltip use:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    private TabControl tabControl1;
    private TabPage tabPage1;
    private TabPage tabPage2;

    private void MyTabs()
    {
        this.tabControl1 = new TabControl();
        this.tabPage1 = new TabPage();
        this.tabPage2 = new TabPage();

        this.tabControl1.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {
            this.tabPage1,
            this.tabPage2});
        this.tabControl1.Location = new Point(35, 25);
        this.tabControl1.Size = new Size(220, 220);

        // Shows ToolTipText when the mouse passes over tabs. 
        this.tabControl1.ShowToolTips = true;

        // Assigns string values to ToolTipText. 
        this.tabPage1.ToolTipText = "myTabPage1";
        this.tabPage2.ToolTipText = "myTabPage2";

        this.Size = new Size(300, 300);
        this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {
            this.tabControl1});
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        MyTabs();
    }

    static void Main() 
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. Then whats the difference between `control.ToolTipText` and `toolTip1.SetToolTip(control, text)` If I can use that control property without using `toolTip` control?

Comment: maybe your tooltip is out of scope? you can also look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339524/c-how-do-i-add-a-tooltip-to-a-control)

Comment: or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732140/c-problem-displaying-tooltip-over-a-disabled-control)

Answer (score 1):

Actually kinda tricky, so make sure that from the tabControl1 properties "ShowToolTips" is True.

1. the form1 has a tooltip1 and a TabControl named tabControl1 with multiple tabs for testing
2. tabControl1 has a collection of tabs
3. edit the collection and set the tab you want to have the tooltip "ToolTip on toolTip" and ToolTipText to "your message here"