# Display tool tip in disabled control

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I know this was already asked here: [Displaying tooltip over a disabled control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732140/c-problem-displaying-tooltip-over-a-disabled-control)

But it doesn't work for me. I have a `TabControl` control, with a `TabPage` in it. In the `TabPage`, I have a `TableLayoutPanel`. My disabled controls are inside that panel.

The problem is that the event does not fire when the mouse is over the disabled control. I tried the code in the `MouseMove` of the Form, the `TabControl`, the `TabPage`, the `TableLayoutPanel`  and the disabled controls themselves, but none of them are working. Is there another solution?

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to try the MouseMove event of the TabPage.

Comment: I did try it, just forgot to mention it :)

Comment: Which controls are you specifically disabling?  Any container controls?

Comment: They are text boxes and comboboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling the GetChildAtPoint function from the container control, which in your case, sounds like the TableLayoutPanel:

```
Control control = tableLayoutPanel1.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location);
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Also, to make it more general, I casted the sender of the event as a control and used it to the the Child (In my current case, it's always the tablelayoutpanel, but I might use it elsewhere too).